# Is there any way to encrypt and decrypt an arabic string in java or c#?

Tags: java

I want to encrypt and decrypt an arabic string in java, When I try to encrypt arabic string it convert like this,
input :  كيف حالكم
apply encryption
output : ?????????
after decryption.
Can we encrypt arabic words like english words in and then decrypt them without any problem or weird text like ???? this.

```
 public static byte[] encrypt(String value)
{
    try
    {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);

        byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());

        return encrypted;
        // return Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encrypted)
{
    try
    {
        IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(initVector.getBytes("UTF-8"));
        SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

        return new String(original);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
public static String encryptAndEncodeString(String value)
{
    value = new String(new Base64().encode(encrypt(value)));
    value = encodeBase64(value);
    return value;
}

public static String decodeAndDecryptString(String value)
{
    value = decodeBase64(value);
    value = decrypt(value);
    return value;
}
```

Comment: your encryption function does not work at all, you forgot to set the iv. Change: "cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);" to "cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);". For testing I used my own Base64 en-/decoding function as you did not provide them.

Comment: Also always specify charset for String -> byte[] & byte[] -> String conversions, e.g.: `original.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)` as your default charset could be different.